# Prove existence of infimum and supremum under a partial order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Consider the partial order $(A^*,\leq)$, where A is a set, and $A^*=\{P$ $|$ $P$ is a prtition on A$\}$

Let the order relation be:

$P_{1} \leq P_{2} \leftrightarrow \forall p_{1} \in P_{1} \exists p_{2} \in P_{2}: p_{1} \subseteq p_{2}$

I already proved that $\leq$ is a partial order, (transitivity, 
antisymmetry and reflection).

Consider the following set $\{P_{1},P_{2}\}$, then prove that exist $P_{3}$ so it is infimum (same for supremum) of the proposed set.

Notice that every $p \in P$ is a subset of A and $\forall P$

$\bigcup_{p \in P} p =A$

I already found an upper and lower bound. I was thinking that maybe there has to be something like a supremum axiom for this cases, I let you my advances:

Upper bound = $\{a,b,c,...\}$

Lower bound = $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},...\}$

I know that if we have that bounds we can eventually find better ones, but if we can not then we already have these ones, in that sense it has to exist infimum and supremum, but I don't know how to write it formally.

Comment: You are doing well, just fix your upper bound. If we denote $\mathcal{L}=\bigcup_{\{a\}\subset A}$ and $\mathcal{U}=\{A\},$ then prove that for any $P\in A*$ holds $\mathcal{L}\;\leq\;P\;\leq\;\mathcal{U}.$

Comment: This proves that $\mathbb L$ and $\mathbb U$ are the minimal and maximal element of the whole partial order, which is a nice thing to know, of course. But does not lead to any insight into what the supremum/infimum of any two partitions can be.

Comment: Hint: Prove that $\min(P_1, P_2) = \{X \neq \emptyset: X = p_1 \cap p_2$ for some $p_1 \in P_1, p_2 \in P_2\}$.

Comment: Then if $min(P_{1},P_{2})$ is an infimum the set has supremum since it is inferiorly complete (i don't know how is it called in english), but for this to work the $p_{1},p_{2}$ you mentioned doesn't have to match only between them, I mean if $P_{1}=\{p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\}$ and if you have $p_{4} \in P_{2}$, you have to consider  $p_{4} \cap p_{n} \forall p_{n} \in P_{1}$, other way you will not neccesary obtain a partition of A. In the other hand if you make it as I said you only obtain {A}. am I crazy, maybe i just don't see it

Comment: It is as I wrote, you take *every* $p_1 \in P_1$ and cut it with *every* $p_2 \in P_2$, throw away the empty sets and you get the minimum=infimum. I'm not sure what exactly you "don't see", of course proving that this is the minimum is not trivial, just start making it clear to yourself that what I wrote is really a partition, then that it is $\le$ both $P_1$ and $P_2$ and finally that it is the minimum. On this problem you don't get to use any fancy "lemma", this is ground work of doing things be the definition.

Comment: Ok i got it, i think we were saying the same actually (about how min() was defined), but i got confused before and thought min($P_{1},P_{2}$) = A, sorry, I finished the whole proof now, it is all correct, you first prove min() is infimum and as you also find the bounds the set is inferiorly complete, then it has supremum. Ty guys!